# Processing error: Cannot invoke blurImage(int, int, int) on the primitive type int

Tags: java, processing

I recently made a program in processing Java to load an image and blur it but am now putting this function into a class as a method and got this error:

> Cannot invoke blurImage(int, int, int) on thee primitive type int

my class:

```
//create class called ImageProcessing where all image editing methonds will be
class ImageProcessing {
  //create function "blurImage" which takes in an xOffset, a yOffset, and a blur amount
  //xOffset and yOffset is changing where the grid starts so the make the blurring algorithm less pixelated using other methods when calling this function
  //the blur amount is how big each box in the grid is
  void blurImage(int xOffset, int yOffset, int blurAmount) {
    //loop through x in the image starting at the negative xOffset and incrementing by the blurAmouint / 2
    //the negative xOffset's purpose is to start the offset off the grid so as to blur the whole image no matter the offset
    //incrementing by the blurAmount / 2 is done because it needs to go in both directions
    for (int x = -xOffset; x < pic.width; x += blurAmount / 2) {
      //loop through the same way for the y so that we can got though in 2 dimentions instead of just 1
      for (int y = -yOffset; y < pic.height; y += blurAmount / 2) {
        //create a 2D array called p that is the size of the blur amount, the size of the box; this is the box
        color[][] p = new color[blurAmount][blurAmount];
        //initialize variables that are the averages of each color channel
        int redAverage = 0;
        int greenAverage = 0;
        int blueAverage = 0;

        //loop through the blurAmount in both dimentions to refrence all the pixels in the p array
        for (int a = 0; a < blurAmount; a++) {
          for (int b = 0; b < blurAmount; b++) {
            //fill the array with the colors of the current box on the grid so i can refrence them easily
            p[a][b] = pic.get(x + a, y + b);
            //these lines add up the Red Green and Blue channels into their individual variables
            //the "(p[a][b] >> 16) & 0xFF" is first shifting the hexidecimal number over into the correct position and then chopping off the extra bits to the right
            redAverage += (p[a][b] >> 16) & 0xFF;
            greenAverage += (p[a][b] >> 8) & 0xFF;
            blueAverage += p[a][b] & 0xFF;
          }
        }

        //dividing the red averages by the square of the blurAmount
        //the squaring is needed to find the area in pixels, this makes the average
        redAverage /= (int)(blurAmount * blurAmount);
        greenAverage /= (int)(blurAmount * blurAmount);
        blueAverage /= (int)(blurAmount * blurAmount);

        //create color from the average values
        color blur = color(redAverage, greenAverage, blueAverage);

        //loop through the current box on the grid the same way as before
        for (int a = 0; a < blurAmount; a++) {
          for (int b = 0; b < blurAmount; b++) {
            //setting all the pixels in the box to the color of the averages
            //the reason for the "x + a" and the "y + b":
            //find the location of the pixels in the box relative to the top left corner of it
            pic.set(x + a, y + b, blur);
          }
        }
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

my code to call it:

```
/*
//The purpose of this program is to create a blurring algorithm that can
//adjust to pixelate or blur the image at different levels.
//
//We first need to split th image into a grid and work with each box on the grid individually.
//After this we get all the color values from each pixel in the box and store it in our code.
//We can then add all the reds together, the greens together, and the blues together and divide each by the number of pixels.
//Next, we turn all the three average into a color variable and set all the pixels in the current box the that color
//
//If we run this multiple times, we can change the blur amount each time and offset the grid to get less pixelated results, we can get a smoother image.
//
//Kwown Issues:
//none so far
//
//Created by Matthew Teta
*/

//create instance of my ImageProcessing claa
ImageProcessing i = new ImageProcessing();

//Make sketch full screen
boolean sketchFullScreen() {
  return true;
}

//initialize image
PImage pic;

void setup() {
  //load image from file and save it into pic PImage
  pic = loadImage("image.jpg");
  //create window at size of picture
  size(pic.width, pic.height);
  background(255);
  frameRate(1);
}
//maxBlur is the starting variable for the blur; TL;DR sets the first size of the grid boxes; also used for the temperary blur value running later in my code
float maxBlur = 16;
//initialize the blurDecrement
int blurDecrement = 0;
//create variable that is the amount of times the blurring algorithm is run
//RECOMENDATION: make the blur half of the maxBlur
//the lower the value the more pixelated
int blur = 1;
//simple boolean so that my code for running the blur is only run once at the beginning
boolean first = true;

void draw() {
  //calling "first()" if this is the first iteration
  if (first) {
    first();
  }

  //save image in file called "blurred-img" as a jpg
  pic.save("blurred-img.jpg");

  //setting the variable for runniong the code once to false so that is won't be run again
  first = false;
}

//create function first that is only run one time when the program is run
void first() {  
  //first find the blurDecrement so that we will get a smooth transition for the number of iterations of the blur algorithm we have
  blurDecrement = (int)(maxBlur / blur);

  //iterate through blur, the number of times to blur
  for (int i = 0; i < blur; i++) {
    //run blur algorithm at the blurDecrement for the x and y offsets using the maxBlur
    //remember: the maxBlur is also used to store the value after being decremented in the loop
    i.blurImage(blurDecrement, blurDecrement, round(maxBlur));
    //draw the image on the canvas at the top left point, (0, 0)
    image(pic, 0, 0);

    //decrement maxBlur by the blurDecrement value
    maxBlur -= blurDecrement;
  }
}
```

The error is on the line

> i.blurImage(blurDecrement, blurDecrement, round(maxBlur));

I have searched the internet for the problem but have not gotten what I wanted. Thanks in advance for a response!

Comment: Have you tried `int var = round(maxBlur)` and then putting `var` in as a parameter?

Comment: I just tried that and got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT** in the below loop, you declare `i` as an int in: `int i = 0`. Remember, local variables take precedence over global variables. Try renaming your object `i` to something like `object_i`. i.e. `ImageProcessing object_i = new ImageProcessing();`

```
for (int i = 0; i < blur; i++) {

    i.Func(foo);// the problem = object name is same as int variable name.

//stuff
}
```